# How to calculate Vibration Frequency (Hz or G or Equivalent) using Accelerometer Sensor of Mobile phone?

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin, android-sensors

I'm developing a android mobile app. I would like to calculate Vibration frequency using accelerometer sensor that provides m/s^2 tri-axis output (x, y, z).
Samples:
x: 9.89403849
y: 5.99348859
z: 10.9458495

Its a React Native app and I use the library https://react-native-sensors.github.io/docs/Usage.html for accessing the sensor's output.

```
constructor() {
  super();

  this.state = {
    value: null
  }

  setUpdateIntervalForType(SensorTypes.accelerometer, 1000);
}

componentWillMount() {
 const subscription = accelerometer.subscribe(({ x, y, z, timestamp }) =>
    this.setState({
      value: z
   })
 );
}
```

Is it possible to calculate the Vibration Frequency using the above mobile accelerometer sensor's output and how?

Comment: Usually smartphone Accelerometers have resolution of 5ms, so they can return a value every 5milliseconds. So the max detectable frequency is 200Hz. Is it enough for you?

Answer (score 2):

You need to gather a sample time-series of acceleration data, then apply a [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) decompose the data into the constituent frequency components, assuming there is a clear signal at all. There are a couple of things to consider:

- The data should have a temporal resolution that's at least an order of magnitude smaller than the expected frequency
- The sample should have a total length at least a few times the period of the expected frequency
- If there is no clear signal (phone is lying still, etc) there will be still a result of the calculation, but you need to have a measure of confidence to discard results below some arbitrary threshold of confidence.
- The acceleration data provides three spatial axis but you only want one result number? Then you need to consider how to define that number in terms of the three seperate frequencies that may result from the calculation.